# Database Error (exp_security_hashes)

Tags: database, error

I've been getting errors related to the exp_security_hashes table and it's always this statement:

```
Unknown column 'ip_address' in 'where clause'
```

[image: Image of Database Error]
Normally I would be looking at the add-on but this same issue/error has happened while using different add-ons.

Can I create the ip_address column in the exp_security_hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2.5.4 release changed the `exp_security_hashes` table structure. Any addons that were attempting to manually create an XID hash (EE uses them for secure form processing) are likely to have been caught out by this.

In your case it looks as though the Rating module is the culprit. It doesn't look as though Solspace have released a patch yet so you'd need to request one in case they're not already aware of the problem.

This will probably affect quite a few addons, so that would explain why you're seeing errors relating to more than just the Ratings module.

[If you're using Missing Link I posted [a fix](http://www.vayadesign.net/software/missing-link/release-notes) for this yesterday.]

Comment: WOW how in the world was I suppose to figure that out? Thanks Dom!

Comment: This is why we're waiting before upgrading to 2.5.5 (EllisLab also released a hot fix for a date issue), we use a lot of 3rd Party Add-ons, we figured we'd allow add-on upgrades to happen first, then update.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some sort of upgrade process didn't complete all the way. Did you run the updater and ever get an error during the process?

What you could do is do a full new local install, look at the local table in phpmyadmin, find the format and length etc of the field, then add it to the remote version that is looking for it.

I don't know if this will keep the error from happening, you just might push it on to a different error, but it could work as well. In the end if it doesn't work, you could always remove the field again.

** Although saying all of that, isn't the addon builder part of some of solspace's offering - At least some older versions?